# Read second sheet of xlsx file from various subdirectories of a main directory R

Tags: r, readxl, openxlsx

I want to read the sheet that contains the word "All"or "all" of an excel workbook for every subdirectory based on a specific pattern.
I have tried `list.files()`  but it does not work properly.

```
files_to_read = list.files(
  path = common_path,        # directory to search within
  pattern = "X - GEN", # regex pattern, some explanation below
  recursive = TRUE,          # search subdirectories
  full.names = TRUE          # return the full path
)
data_lst = lapply(files_to_read, read.xlsx)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your sub-directories have a similar name that can be identifiable?

Assumption, let's say:

1. your sub-directory starts with 'this' and
2. the files that are saved in sub-directory starts with the file name 'my_file'
3. the tab that you are trying to read in contains the word 'all'.

If the tab that you are reading in is located in same position (e.g. 2nd tab of every file) then it is easier as you can specify the `sheet` within `read.xlsx` as `sheet = 2` but if this is not the case then one way you could do is by creating your own function that allows for this.

Then

```
library(openxlsx)

# getting the name of subdirectories starting with the word 'this'
my_dir <- list.files(pattern = "^this", full.names = TRUE)

# getting the name of the files starting with 'my_file', e.g. my_file.xlsx, my_file2.xlsx
my_files <- list.files(my_dir, pattern = "^my_file", full.names = TRUE)

my_read_xlsx <- function(files_to_read, sheets_to_read) {
  
  # files to import
  wb <- loadWorkbook(files_to_read)
  
  # getting the sheet names that contain 'all' or any other strings that you specify
  # ignore.case is there so that case is not sensitive when reading in excel tabs
  ws <- names(wb)[grepl(sheets_to_read, names(wb), ignore.case = TRUE)]
  
  # reading in the excel tab specified as above
  xl_data <- read.xlsx(wb, ws)
  
  return(xl_data)
  
}

# Using the function created above and import tabs containing 'all'
my_list <- lapply(my_files, FUN = function(x) my_read_xlsx(x, sheet = "ALL"))

# Converting the list into a data.frame
my_data <- do.call("rbind", my_list)
```